# Split Delimited Cell Record Into Rows Performance

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I have 2 columns

```
COLUMN1 || COLUMN2
15      || 23|45|65|44|66|15
34      || 45|21|16|34|79
```

I want to distinguish `COLUMN2` into rows, and merge with some special syntax like `$0:15$1:23$1:45$1:65$1:44$1:66`. To solve this here there is 2 solution

1. I can separate levels such as

```sql
SELECT COLUMN1,COLUMN2, REGEXP_SUBSTR(COLUMN2,'[^|]\d+',1,LEVEL)
FROM TABLE_NAME
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(COLUMN2,'[^|]\d+',1,LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
```

2. I can separate `COLUMN2` to other columns and merge it back. But this will create lots of `regexp_substr` functioning.

Problem is here I have huge performance impact. Taking so long time. I'm looking for more efficient way to do it. Row count over `1M`.

**Edit 1 :**
COLUMN1 will be started as `$0:`, if COLUMN2 has same value in separated, it wont be considered in result.

Expected output :

```
$0:15$1:23$1:45$1:65$1:44$1:66
$0:34$1:45$1:21$1:16$1:79
```

Note that Column1 cant be first element of column2

Comment: *"I'm looking for more efficient way to do it."*  As all methods would require to scan the FULL table obvious is that you should normalize..

Comment: This question is really more complicated. Actually separating into rows is a must, because there might be 2,3 rows need to be distinguished and merge in a single line. I'm using `full parallel(8)` hints to increase performance. I asked this question in simple way to get some simple ideas. Now currently I'm developing your ideas in my environment. Thanks a lot @RaymondNijland

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong but it looks like a simple replace case as following:

```
SELECT '$0:' || REPLACE('23|45|65|44|66','|',' $1:') FROM DUAL;
```

Please comment if you need anything else.

**-- UPDATE --**

According to additional condition added in the question, You can try this now:

```
SQL> WITH MY_TAB(COL1,COL2)
  2  AS (
  3  SELECT 15, '23|45|65|44|66|15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4  SELECT  34, '45|21|16|34|79' FROM DUAL
  5  )SELECT
  6      '$0:'
  7      || COL1
  8      || '$1:'
  9      || REPLACE(REPLACE(COL2, '|' || COL1, ''), '|', '$1:') AS DESIRED_VALUE
 10  FROM
 11      MY_TAB;

DESIRED_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$0:15$1:23$1:45$1:65$1:44$1:66
$0:34$1:45$1:21$1:16$1:79

SQL>
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Nice point of view, but there is some conditions, forgot to mention in question, I added.

Comment: Please add the expected output too

Comment: added expected output

Comment: That will not work if COL1 is the first value in the csv list of col2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following syntax to generate your expected result:

```
RTRIM('$0'|| column1 || 
  REPLACE( '$1:' || REPLACE(column2,'|',' $1:') || '$'
         , '$1:'||column1||'$'
         , '$')
     ,'$')
```

Also you can use recursive query instead of your original query, which get rid of duplicated rows:

```
WITH TABLE_NAME (column1, column2) AS (
       select 15 , '23|45|65|44|66' from dual UNION all
       select 34 , '45|21|16|95|79' from dual)
   , rec (column1, pos, col2, column2) AS (
       SELECT column1, 1, REGEXP_SUBSTR(COLUMN2,'\d+'), column2 FROM table_name
       UNION ALL
       SELECT column1, pos + 1, REGEXP_SUBSTR(COLUMN2,'\d+',1,pos + 1), column2
         FROM rec
        WHERE REGEXP_SUBSTR(COLUMN2,'\d+',1,pos + 1) IS NOT NULL )
SELECT * FROM rec
```

I would suggest to create a new table and split the csv column there to get a better data model, then it would be easier to do all opartions on that data. Working with csv data is allways a mess.

Comment: Creating new table is not proper way currently in our data model and regex as I mention in question is have huge performance impact. I’m mentioning, your recursive query. But first one is also solving problem. Thanks

Comment: You can use views to mimic old data model to not need to change current logic and can then replace logic piece by piece. But thats just some advice, i have csv logic myself in application and regret every minute i have to deal with that stuff.